# How to validate a JsonObject using JsonPath?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using the code below to validate testcases:

```
JToken doc = JToken.Parse(json);
IEnumerable<JToken> result = doc.SelectTokens(jsonPath);
bool success = result.Any();
```

The success criteria is anything returned for the given json queried with the jsonPath (which contains the success criteria/condition).

The problem I have is that i can only validate json arrays this way. If I need to assess a single json object this won't work.

Example:

```
jsonPath = "$[?(@.Artist=='Britney')]"
```

On the json array this path works:

```
[{
  "Artist": "Britney",
  "Genre": "Pop/Rock",
}]
```

On the json object this path doesn't work:

```
{
  "Artist": "Britney",
  "Genre": "Pop/Rock",
}
```

Is there an alternative path or any other approach i can use to validate json object?

Comment: Why not define a class that matches the structure of the json object?

Comment: The reason is: I am writing a separate test, and I want to decouple from the json structure. I use jsonPath as a success criteria to assess url call expectations.